# Apply a function to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe 'df' that looks like this:

```
                Y        E
1312  2.098650e-10  4.05909
1313  9.294030e-10  4.11673
1314  5.596410e-10  4.18051
1315  7.395250e-10  4.18648
1316  3.997430e-10  4.20233
```

I want to apply a function to the values in columns Y and E to a new column 'func_d'.

```
def func(typ, Y, E):
    if typ=='d':
        return E/Y
    else:
        return E*Y

def func_d(Y,E):
    return func('d', Y, E)
```

I get

> TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 1312')

when I do this:

```
df['func_d'] = df.apply(func_d(df['Y'],df['E']), axis=1)
```

Am I not passing the variables to `func_d` correctly?

Comment: I found out that this works: df['func_d'] = df.apply(lambda x: func_d(x['Y'],x['E']), axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

What is 'typ'? Do you want that as an argument? The function should ideally have row or column as an argument. So, something like this may work:

```
def func_d(row, typ='d'):
    E = row['E']
    Y = row['Y']
    if typ == 'd':
        return E/Y
    else:
        return E*Y

df['func_d'] = df.apply(lambda row:func_d(row,'d'), axis = 1)
```

Without the lambda function, it would be

```
df['func_d'] = df.apply(func_d, axis = 1, args = ("d"))
```

Comment: Thank you. 'typ' is a little more complicated than what I stated in the original question. There are several possible values for type and what func returns depends on the value of typ.

Comment: You don't need the lamba, you can pass additional positional or keyword arguments to apply using the args and **kwds arguments. Check out the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: @SimonN Thanks. Updated my answer.